# Haskell return custom datatype

Tags: haskell

I can not get this method working at all. Getting errors all the time. Where am I making a mistake? It is supposed to accept string array of numbers, take the head, create a point. However, I think the problem is in the recursion call.

```
data Point = Point(Int, Int) -- y, x
instance Show Point where
  show (Point(y, x)) = "(" ++ show x ++ "," ++ show y ++ ")"

gimmePoints :: String -> Point                       
gimmePoints (x:xs) = do Point(1,2)
                        gimmePoints xs
```

Comment: What do you mean by "string array of numbers", given that the Point constructor takes two numbers? How are they separated?

Comment: `Point` doesn't have a `Monad` instance, so `do` notation can't be used. Also, your `Point` type is doubly wrapping the coordinates. There's no need to encapsulate the two points in a tuple; they can simply be wrapped by the `Point` constructor itself: `data Point = Point Int Int`.

Comment: Are you learning Haskell based on a tutorial? Because the `gimmePoints` function, to be blunt, doesn't make much sense. It's not clear what it's supposed to be doing at all, let alone what it actually does. I suggest slowing down and trying a simpler task, perhaps more in line with a beginner's Haskell guide such as [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

Comment: Please show an intended *call* of `gimmePoints`.\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your function has signature `... -> Point`, that means the result should be a point. Nothing else. So you can certainly write

```
gimmePoints :: String -> Point                       
gimmePoints (x:xs) = Point(1,2)
```

That means of course only the first character in the string will be processed. In fact, since you don't actually *use* that character or anything else in the string in any way, you might as well write this as

```
gimmePoints _ = Point(1,2)
```

I don't suppose that's what you want.

`do` syntax at any rate doesn't make any sense here, that is for *monadic* (“side-effectful”) *actions*. For instance, if you want for each character the point to be printed to the screen, you could do

```
gimmePoints' (_:xs) = do
      print $ Point(1,2)
      gimmePoints' xs
```

In this case, the result of `gimmePoints` would not be `Point` at all, but rather an IO action with no result (because the “results” are sent to the screen instead)

```
gimmePoints' :: String -> IO ()
```

A more sensible, or at least more functional-programming-ish version you could actually want is

```
gimmePoints'' :: String -> [Point]
gimmePoints'' [] = []
gimmePoints'' (_:xs) = Point (1,2) : gimmePoints'' xs
```

i.e. for each character in the string, *you yield one point in the result*. This would actually better be written

```
gimmePoints'' = map (const $ Point (1,2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Worked.